# Drawing a CachedBitmap in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I try to display a cached Bitmap in Winforms (for performance reasons). I have a problem cause I cant draw it. 
The exaple in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6474581/1676819 says that there should be something like 
`graphics.DrawCachedBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0);` 
I cant find it.

What I've done so far:

- I added Presentationcore.dll as reference
- I created a `CachedBitmap`

`CachedBitmap tempCBm = new CachedBitmap(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"D:\test.bmp")),BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);`

- I tried to draw it with the standard method (causes error)

  ```
  private void CustomPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
  {
          e.Graphics.DrawImage(tempCBm, 0,0);//error
  }
  ```

Can somebody tell me what am I´m doing wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use cached bitmap - but for some reason it is not available in standard C# api. You can circumvent around that however - make a managed C++ library that will encapsulate methods you want to expose to C#.

See my github repo - https://github.com/svejdo1/CachedBitmap

C++ utility class to expose cached bitmap

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;

namespace CachedBitmapUtility {
    public ref class BitmapUtility {
        public:
            static void* CreateCachedBitmapPtr(void* bitmapPtr, void* graphicsHdc) {
                Graphics graphics((HDC)graphicsHdc);
                CachedBitmap* result = new CachedBitmap((Bitmap*)bitmapPtr, &graphics);
                return result;
            }
            static void DisposeCachedBitmap(void* cachedBitmapPtr) {
                delete (CachedBitmap*)cachedBitmapPtr;
            }
            static void DisposeBitmap(void* bitmapPtr) {
                delete (Bitmap*)bitmapPtr;
            }
            static void* GetBitmapPtrFromHICON(void* hicon) {
                return (void*)Bitmap::FromHICON((HICON)hicon);
            }
            static void DrawCachedBitmap(void* hdc, void* cachedBitmapPtr, int x, int y) {
                Graphics graphics((HDC)hdc);
                graphics.DrawCachedBitmap((CachedBitmap*)cachedBitmapPtr, x, y);

            }
    };
}
```

Example usage from WinForm application:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form {
  IntPtr m_BitmapPtr;
  IntPtr m_CachedBitmapPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

  public MainForm() {
    InitializeComponent();

    Bitmap bitmap;
    using (var stream = typeof(MainForm).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("FormApplication.character.png")) {
      bitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
    }
    unsafe {
      m_BitmapPtr = (IntPtr)BitmapUtility.GetBitmapPtrFromHICON((void*)bitmap.GetHicon());
    }
  }

  protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e) {
    // TODO: refactor - dispose should happen in Dispose event
    unsafe {
      BitmapUtility.DisposeBitmap((void*)m_BitmapPtr);
      BitmapUtility.DisposeCachedBitmap((void*)m_CachedBitmapPtr);
    }
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    var graphics = e.Graphics;
    IntPtr hdc;
    if (m_CachedBitmapPtr == IntPtr.Zero) {
      hdc = graphics.GetHdc();
      unsafe {
        m_CachedBitmapPtr = (IntPtr)BitmapUtility.CreateCachedBitmapPtr((void*)m_BitmapPtr, (void*)hdc);
      }
      graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
    }

    hdc = graphics.GetHdc();
    unsafe {
      BitmapUtility.DrawCachedBitmap((void*)hdc, (void*)m_CachedBitmapPtr, 0, 0);
    }
    graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ondrej - Do you have a compiled DLL from that c++ code?

Comment: I have just implemented your code on one of my programs it has improved its performance by about 400%! So, thank you. However, trying to use ScaleTransform (which I added to your `CachedBitmapUtility` class), produces no apparent output; that is, nothing appears to be rendered. Do you know why?

Comment: @xfx - I do - you can't use ScaleTransform or RotateTransform if you draw cached bitmap. Check out the value that DrawCachedBitmap function returns - I bet it returns WrongState. Only workaround here is to generate bitmap in various scales (or rotations, etc.) and cache the scaled/rotated/etc. version instead.

Answer (score 3):

[`CachedBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nl-gdiplusheaders-cachedbitmap) is not available through .NET. It is a feature of GDI+. Use [`Bitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap) instead. If you need to optimize for performance, then you can use the [`unsafe` context in C# for faster bitmap access](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx).

A nice tutorial is available here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp.

Comment: Does that improves also the time the bitmap need for getting painted? I thought this improves only get/setpixel...

Comment: If you are using the unsafe approach, then you will need to implement your own drawing functions. If you want to draw using the `Graphics` object, then you will have to use the slower, `Bitmap`, version.