# Bitmap repaint in picturebox lagging

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I have application in which you can draw some shapes, catch them by vertices and move the vertice. I store vertices of a shapes in the `List` and repaint whole list of the objects (when the vertice is catch and mouse moves)in the bitmap which is assigned to `PictureBox.Image`. When I add more than 5 shapes, the moving vertice is lagging. Here is a piece of code:

```
    private void DrawFullList()
    {
        if (pictureBox2.Image != null)
        {
            pictureBox2.Image.Dispose();
            g.Dispose();
        }
        graphic = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height);
        g = Graphics.FromImage(graphic);
        pictureBox2.Image = graphic;
        for (int i = 0; i < PointsList.Count; i++)
            Draw(BrushList[i], PointsList[i]);
    }
    private void Draw(Brush brush, Point[] points)
    {
        Pen PathPen = new Pen(brush);
        PathPen.Width = 3;
        if (points.Length == 2)
            g.DrawLine(PathPen, points[0], points[1]);
        else
            g.FillPolygon(brush,points);
        pictureBox2.Image = graphic;
    }
```

If there anyway to imporve it? I was trying to `graphic.Clear(Color.Transparent)` but there was no way to change the size of bitmap ( the function is used when we resizing the window).

Any tips?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# WinForms - Anyone know of a C# GDI library not SLOW GDI+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391911/c-sharp-winforms-anyone-know-of-a-c-sharp-gdi-library-not-slow-gdi)

Answer (score 0):

I found simple mistake what actually makes the lags. `pictureBox2.Image = graphic;` was executed two times in a row, when `PointsList.Count != 0` what was creating laggs.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks overcomplicated and ineffective. Also your code rely too hard on garbage collector (it is a good practice to dispose `Graphics`, `Brush` and `Pen` classes right after use).

I think in your case best idea is to avoid creating and disposing bitmaps completely. You can replace your `PictureBox` with, for example, `Panel` class, subscribe to its `Paint` event and paint your shapes inside this method. When position of your vertices changes simply call `Invalidate` method to repaint your shapes inside panel.